# Run every bin in a directory one by one

Tags: bash, shell

Say, there is a directory, the two bin files behind it. But I don't know the file's name. Any way can run the bin files one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Start every file in a folder:

```
find <foldername> -type f -exec {} \;
```

Is searchs in foldername about every file. The filename is usable with the `{}` placeholder for a command. Because there is no command other than the placeholder the filename will be executed.

Comment: `find <foldername> -name "*.bin" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec {} \;`: only the "bin" files, and don't go into subfolders.

Comment: so, if the commend is bash. it should be `find <foldername> -name "*.bin" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec {bash} \;`?

Comment: Did you mean `-exec bash {} \;`?